# How disable change language in number pad in iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield, numpad

I have texFiled I'm my view controller and i set number pad for that like this:

```
self.phoneTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

And now i want user just can enter english number in text field(can not change language)

[image]

Comment: can you elobrate `can enter english number in text field(can not change language)`

Comment: i want change language button in keyboard be disable. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: reza_khalafi : Please share your suggestion what you will do for restrict the language option in the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This only applies for iOS 10 or later and for number pad)

Swift

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
```

Objective C

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableNumberPad;
```

Answer (score 5):

**NO**,we can't `disable` or `Hidden` the keyboard properties,  it is not possible to handle  the default property of `Keyboardtype`in `iOS`, if you want to make it own customization then you go for `Custom Keyboard` Concept. else try once with another [keyboard Types](http://zuzara.com/blog/2010/07/01/screenshots-for-uikeyboardtype/)

**Choice 2**

in that place you can add one `Overlay` for disable , you can get the sample from [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-to-custimize-a-keyboard.html).but

> If Apple figures out that the key is covered or. disabled they will most likely reject the app.

Comment: Awesome.. !! Usefull...!!